# Multivariate statistical criterion to select key variables

Tags: multicollinearity, multivariate-regression

I have a complex dataset with several predictor variables $X_i$ ($i=1,...,m$) and several outcome variables $Y_j$   $(j=1,...,n$). The problem is that many of the predictor variables are correlated with one another, and the outcome variables are also correlated. I would like to have a robust procedure to differenciate the important predictor and output variables (i.e. which predictor variables are better able to explain each of the output variables, and which output variables are more predictable in general). I tried PCA on the $X_i$, but it seems that it gives excessive importance to the most correlated $X_i$ variables, regarless of their explanatoory power on the $Y_j$ (which honestly makes sense, as the algorithm is not looking at the $Y_j$). I have also looked at bibliography and have seen a plethora of methods: Canonical Correlation Analysis, Multiple Regression, stepwise regression, lasso... But the sources widely differed on their claims of efficacy of each of these methods. So is there a robust, widespread method for tacking this problem?

Comment: I don't know about robust, but if you have multiple y's and x's you can use PLS regression to analyze them both simultaneously.

Comment: I don't think there is a general recommendation, it depends on your goals and the nature of the data. I usually try to do dimension reduction as my first choice but my goal is usually inference, not prediction. To me it sounds like some regularization method might work for you (LASSO, Elastic net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Component subtraction** would be appropriate for these circumstances.  First, run PCA on the $\mathbf{Y}$ matrix of correlated outcomes. Then identify the major (greatest eigenvalue) and then generate the principal component (PC) score vector associated with that eigenvalue/eigenvector pair.  This will result in an $n \times 1$ matrix $\mathbf{F}_y$ of PC scores.  Now regress $\mathbf{Y}$ on $\mathbf{F}_y$ using multivariate normal regression with a constant term, and get the residuals, which are equal to the all the $y-\hat{y}$.  The residual matrix will now be called $\mathbf{E}_y$, and will **represent the original y-values with strong correlation removed.**

Do the same for the $\mathbf{X}$ matrix of correlated inputs. That is, identify the major eigenvalues and then generate the PC score vector associated with that eigenvalue/eigenvector pair.  This will result in an $n \times 1$ matrix $\mathbf{F}_x$ of PC scores.  Now regress $\mathbf{X}$ on $\mathbf{F}_x$ using multivariate normal regression with a constant term, and get the residuals, which are equal to the all the $x-\hat{x}$.  The residual matrix will now be called $\mathbf{E}_x$, which **represent the original predictor values with strong correlation removed.**

Finally, the answer will result from regressing $\mathbf{E}_y$ on $\mathbf{E}_x$ using multivariate normal regression.

A key point is that you only want to use the major eigenvalue/eigenvector pair, and don't want to generate PC scores for eigenvalues $\lambda_j>1$ and then run the regressions, since the resulting residuals will have the entire signal in $\mathbf{Y}$ or $\mathbf{X}$ wiped out.